# Flex containers and large width of an image inside an item

Tags: html, css, image, flexbox

I'm having a very weird problem with scaling images inside a flex container.

This is my flex container:

```css
.flex {
  display: flex;
  background-color: red;
}

.scaleimages img {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 1000px;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex">
  <div class="item1">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
  </div>
  <div class="item2 scaleimages">
  <img src="https://image.shutterstock.com/image-photo/colorful-flower-on-dark-tropical-260nw-721703848.jpg">
  </div>
</div>
```

As you see, `.scaleimages` class, with a really simple trick, it scales correctly all the images inside the item avoiding any type of overflow.

If I set the image to a medium-large width with `width="100000"`, the image is still scaled correctly avoiding overflows.

```css
.flex {
  display: flex;
  background-color: red;
}

.scaleimages img {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 1000px;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex">
  <div class="item1">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
  </div>
  <div class="item2 scaleimages">
  <img src="https://image.shutterstock.com/image-photo/colorful-flower-on-dark-tropical-260nw-721703848.jpg" width="100000">
  </div>
</div>
```

Now, if I set the image to a very large width with `width="10000000000000"`, the image overflows slightly:

```css
.flex {
  display: flex;
  background-color: red;
}

.scaleimages img {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 1000px;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex">
  <div class="item1">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
  </div>
  <div class="item2 scaleimages">
  <img src="https://image.shutterstock.com/image-photo/colorful-flower-on-dark-tropical-260nw-721703848.jpg" width="10000000000000">
  </div>
</div>
```

You may ask, why should I set such a large width? Because the widht/height values of the image comes from an user input, so he can break the page by setting a very large width.

Why is this happening? There is a way to fix it? Thanks.

Comment: If the image size is controlled by user perhaps you should not allow them to set such a large width/height?

Comment: Agree with @EternalHour, why not just limit the input value to a max of three characters?

Comment: @EternalHour yeah, I can do that, but why? Should I add a check for limiting the size of the image without knowing why I am doing that? If they want to set large dimensions is not a problem for me since is all limited with a clean css edit, as many CMSs do. The problem is this behaviour, why is doing that? I prefer to fix it in a CSS way.

Comment: Why allow the user to break the layout of your page? That's why. Applications always need some type of constraints; Such as file type, form validation, etc.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can also set `width:100%` to the `.scaleimages img` to prevent bigger sizes and thus control the size with your container.

```css
.flex {
  display: flex;
  background-color: red;
}

.scaleimages img {
  width: 100%;
  max-height: 1000px;
}

.scaleimages {
  width: 500px;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex">
  <div class="item1">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
  </div>
  <div class="item2 scaleimages">
  <img src="https://image.shutterstock.com/image-photo/colorful-flower-on-dark-tropical-260nw-721703848.jpg" width="1000000000000000000000">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: While this may answer the question, please update your answer to include the code from the CodePen. Use the Snippet feature here.

Answer (score 0):

You can always fix the size of the image tag, it will not flow over its parent

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>
  <style>
    .flex {
      display: flex;
      background-color: red;
    }
    
    .scaleimages img {
      min-height: 200px;
      max-height: 200px;
      min-width: 200px;
      max-width: 200px;
    }
  </style>
  <div class="flex">
    <div class="item1">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
    </div>
    <div class="item2 scaleimages">
      <img src="https://image.shutterstock.com/image-photo/colorful-flower-on-dark-tropical-260nw-721703848.jpg" width="10000000000000">
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```